# Problems with moving images from train/test/validation split into the right directories

Tags: python, numpy, move, shutil

I am trying to run an image classifier with my own images, based upon the Keras/Colab tutorials. Previously, I was splitting my images into the train/test/validation folders manually and it was working fine. Now I'm having problems when I put all of the images into the base directory and split them.

I'm wondering if I need to copy the images directly to the proper directories after using numpy to split images into the train, test, validation sets.

```
base_dir = 'drive/Colab/EV3/Base/'
like = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Like')
dislike = os.path.join(base_dir, 'Dislike')

trn_dir = 'drive/Colab/EV3/Train/'
val_dir = 'drive/Colab/EV3/Valid/'
tst_dir = 'drive/Colab/EV3/Test/'

trn_like = os.path.join(trn_dir, 'Like')
val_like = os.path.join(val_dir, 'Like')
tst_like = os.path.join(tst_dir, 'Like')

trn_disl = os.path.join(trn_dir, 'Dislike')
val_disl = os.path.join(val_dir, 'Dislike')
tst_disl = os.path.join(tst_dir, 'Dislike')
```

```
like_fnames.sort ()   
np.random.shuffle(like_fnames)

disl_fnames = os.listdir(dislike)
disl_fnames.sort () 
np.random.shuffle(disl_fnames)

trn_like, val_like, tst_like = np.split(like_fnames, [int(.7*len(like_fnames)), int(.85*len(like_fnames))])

trn_disl, val_disl, tst_disl = np.split(disl_fnames, [int(.7*len(disl_fnames)), int(.85*len(disl_fnames))])
```

```
image_size = 640 
batch_size = 112

train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
                rescale=1./255)

validation_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
                rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                trn_dir,  
                target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                batch_size=batch_size,
                class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                val_dir,
                target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                batch_size=batch_size,
                class_mode='binary')
```

The main problem is occurring at the last step, where I should be getting an output of:

> Found 560 images belonging to 2 classes.
>   
> Found 120 images belonging to 2 classes.

But instead I am getting:

> Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes. 
>   
> Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.

Apologies if I have made some big, clear mistake. I'm very new to python and coding and am trying my best to follow the answers and tutorials that I can.